# Perl parsing large Expect output before writing to file

Tags: perl, parsing, expect

I am building a program to poll a network device every 48 hours and record the output user Perl and the Expect module. At the moment, I am saving the output text to a text file and then filtering the text file to get the required information. Originally, this was fine since efficiency wasn't that big of a problem when dealing with file that are only a hundred KB in size and keeping most of the text anyway, but I've found a new command I want to execute remotely on the network device. This command takes an hour and a half to run, creates a text file around 5MB in size and I would probably only be keeping 10KB of information. Using basic file I/O (read a text file, write to a text file) just seems like a bad idea and I keep thinking that there has to be a better way.

What my research has turned up so far:
I should probably be using some sort of Pipe. Something like:

```
open($filehandle, "myCommand");
```

There are other solutions out there, but they seem to imply that I save the ENTIRE file to one variable, when I would like to only save and modify parts of it before writing to a file.
TIEHANDLE works well for overwiting "print", but I don't think that's necessary or will work here.

What I've tried so far:
Redirecting STDOUT using a pipe. Result: Kept on sending the output to a file and couldn't edit the text before it was put in the file.

I have run out of things to Google. If a complete solution is too daunting of a task, a hint as to where the next steps might be would also be greatly appreciated.

Also, if the advantages in terms of processing time are actually minimal (I'm unclear on how  long it takes to process a 5mb test file and will investigate), please let me know.

Comment: The disadvantage of writing a lot of data to pipes is that they typically have a small capacity (1-128KB) and if you don't coordinate reading and writing on the pipe then you can have a deadlock.

Comment: I think I can keep it down to that size. I only need to analyse the output one line at a time and the output itself isn't that fast in the first place.

Comment: If you're using Perl's Expect to log in and execute the commands, then aren't you already reading and parsing some data over your socket connection in Perl? (e.g. waiting for "password:" prompt and so forth) That implies that you must already have a filehandle you're using for that connection, yes…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl can crunch through a 5MB file in no time, I would not worry about trying to redirect the output to a pipe when you can just open the file and parse through it once your job is done running.

```
    open(INPUT, "/path/to/file.log") or die "Can't open file: $!";

    while (<INPUT>) {
    chomp;
      if (/ERROR/) {
        print "Found an error!";
      }
    }
    close(INPUT);
    exit;
```

When you're in the while() loop, you can use regex, split, or whatever you want to find what you're looking for in the file.  The current line is stored in $_.  You will get one iteration for each line of your input file.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ended up coming to this conclusion myself. It took 3 seconds to go through a 10MB file. Sometimes I forget to questions my assumptions. *Facepalm*

Comment: Also, what I was imagining, way back in the day, where the text would be copied and extracted from the network buffer and passed directly to the processor before being stored in memory, would require me writing Assembly and to say the least, be a little bit impractical. Keeping it simple was definitely the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of perl, you can do:

```
open(my $fh, "-|", command => @command_arguments) or die "Error: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
  # Process output of command
}
close $fh or die "Error: $!";
```

On older versions (5.6 or earlier I think), you can do:

```
my $pid = open(my $fh, "-|");
die "Failed to fork: $!" unless defined $pid;
unless ($pid) {
  exec command => @command_arguments;
  die "Failed to exec command: $!";
}
while (<$fh>) {
  # same thing etc.
```

I can't tell from your post if you really need Expect. If you just need to execute a command and capture the output, then the above should be fine.

Comment: I realize that this is my third attempt at a comment and I'm sorry if you've received a notification for each one. I'm using expect because just opening a Telnet session and executing commands would not fill my needs. I need to wait for User/Pass prompts and wait for other commands contained in my script to finish.